# Elastic Beanstalk waiting on instance to pass health checks but Target group shows healthy instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a small elastic beanstalk environment and when the code is uploaded a new instance is launched on the corresponding target group.

Elastic Beanstalk stays on:
`Waiting for instance(s) (i-12345679m123n123) to pass health checks.`

Even tho the target group shows the instances as healthy and the application logs are showing a 200 response for the health check.

Is there any configuration on EB that could be causing this issue.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with IAM Role, which was not enabling the instance to send logs to Cloudwatch.

Comment: Hi, is the IAM role you are referring to, the one associated with the EC2 instance profile? Or the EC2 service role?

Comment: It was a long ago but I would say it was the EC2 service role specified when you create a service through Elastic Beanstalk @forrestDinos